# When returning a array of floats I get an error

Tags: c#, game-engine

When I am trying to return an array of floats I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float[]' to 'float'

I am making a 2d game engine in C# using OpenTK
and I'm working on the vertex class, but I keep geting errors and I'm stuck.

I have tried this:

```
return data[vertices.Length * Size];
```

the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenTK;

namespace RacerEngine
{
    public class Vertex
    {
        private const int Size = 2;

        private Vector2 position;
        public Vector2 Position
        {
            get
            {
                return position;
            }
            set
            {
                position = value;
            }
        }

        public Vertex(Vector2 position)
        {
            this.position = position;
        }

        public static float Process(Vertex[] vertices)
        {
            float[] data = new float[vertices.Length * Size];

            for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                data[i] = vertices[i].position.X;
                data[i + 1] = vertices[i].position.Y;
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `Process` is defined to return a `float`, yet your return statement returns a `float []` from it. Depending on what you need, either change your method signature to

```
public static float[] Process(Vertex[] vertices)
```

or return a single `float` from within the method.

Answer (score 1):

C# is type safe language, means you cannot convert a float value to an array of floats, or you cannot convert an array of floats to a float value.
In your code you are trying to convert an array of floats to a float value, so you must change your code in method definition to:

```
public static float[] Process(Vertex[] vertices)
```